# CSS/Bootstrap: fixed max-width for content layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have noticed, that many websites (SO included) don't shrink to the whole width of the screen, preferring to render content column either of fixed-width or setting max-width property for it. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) dictionary website is a good example for the latter.

Is it possible to create such a layout using Bootstap? I have managed to limit content column width inside it's *col-8-md* div, but there is a huge gap between content and right sidebar on big displays now.

*Live demo:* https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNprzm

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="content-block">
     CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 right-bar">
  RIGHT_BAR
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-block {
   height: 1000px;
   max-width: 1000px;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

.right-bar {
   background-color: pink;
   width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you just want to be sure to have a fixed width for your content but get rid of the space that's happening to the right of it on large screens?

Remove your `margin-right: auto;`. Once you get to a screen size where it's larger than 1000px, it's trying to "center" your `.content-block`

Comment: Is it possible to center both CONTENT-RIGHT_BAR by the middle of the screen vertically?

Comment: I think I might be a little confused of what you're asking. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

EDIT: If you mean - you want to make sure that both your `.content-block` and `.right-bar` stay in the middle of the screen no matter what size the browser. Then I suggest wrapping everything in a `.container` class which will center everything, but then you don't need your max-width on your `.content-block` like your initial question seemed to want.

If I'm just out in left field, help me understand your question a little bit more.